# How to switch tabs programmatically in Android from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have implemented a `TabActivity` which extends `FragmentActivity`. It has 5 tabs each tab is a `Fragment`. What i am looking for is to switch between the tabs programmatically.

**For eg:** if i am in tab4. On button click I want to move from `tab4` to `tab1`. Tried a lot but couldn't find the solution for this.

Tried with the following but it doesn't help.

**From SecondTab**

```
public void switchTabInActivity(String value){
    FirstTab parent;
    parent = (FirstTab) getActivity().getParent();
    parent.switchTab(value);
}
```

**TabActivity**

```
  /** To Change Tab*/
public void switchTab(String tabno){ 
    this.onTabChanged(tabno);
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally i can switch between the tabs programatically from Fragments using the following line of code

```
  TabHost host = (TabHost) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
  host.setCurrentTab(2);
```

Hope it will help some one.

Comment: `android.R.id.tabhost` will throw a nullpointerexception. You are already calling `getActivity.findViewById`
`findViewById(R.id.tabhost)` is the right option

Answer (score 31):

for Material support you switch the tablayout from a fragment in the following ways:

1) send a broadcast that is received by the parent activity which then modifies the tab.

```
context.sendBroadcast(yourintent);
```

2.) A modification of vino's answer,

```
TabLayout tabhost = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
tabhost.getTabAt(2).select();
```

tablayout is the id of the tablayout as defined in your main xml.

Comment: Yes it works, just for information tab indexes starts from 0.

Comment: Hi @Kennedy, my tabhost is not getting initialised. It is showing null. What could be the mistake for NullPointerException??

Comment: It's working now, error was due to a silly mistake of mine. :)

Comment: Hi! Can someone please help me? I am getting an error: `Cannot resolve method 'getActivity()'`.

Comment: @LloydDominic make sure you are working from a fragment.

Answer (score 19):

I have tabs (using TabLayout not TabHost(depreciated))(with Fragments) in my Main Activity in which in my first tab(fragment) with a click listener in the fragment which is for changing the current tab in my MainActivity.

I successfully change the current tab via the below in the onCreateView() method within the fragment.

```
TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout)((MainActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabs.getTabAt(1).select();
```

Comment: this is working answer... upper ones not working because tablayout is null in fragments even if we pass it via constructor..

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5460651/198996

```
((TabActivity) getParent()).getTabHost().setCurrentTab(2)
```

Comment: Thanks Tom i think thats from activity i am looking from Fragment

Comment: @Vino That's from the Fragment. The `getParent()` is a method in Fragment which returns the Activity.

Comment: @Vino try `getActivity()` instead of `getParent()` then.

Comment: yes tried that but i am facing `The method getTabHost() is undefined for the type TabActivity` `((TabActivity) getActivity()).getTabHost().setCurrentTab(3);`

Comment: use `switchTab()` and cast it as your concrete implementation rather than TabActivity then. Note that TabActivity is deprecated.

Comment: @Vino Implement a method `getTabHost()` in your TabActivity, which returns the TabHost...

Comment: Found an answer Tom.I have answered my question. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Well, that's basically what I said. Anyway, good to hear you solved your problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using TabLayout instead of TabHost , I suggest a modification to [BENN1TH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1423608/benn1th/)'s   answer that worked for me:

```
  TabLayout tabs = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
  tabs.getTabAt(tabNumber).select();
```

(The difference is `R.id.tab_layout`)

Answer (score 1):

for kotlin , Please use this form fragment

```
 activity!!.<tab_id_in_xml>.getTabAt(tab_number)!!.select()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach in 'newer' kotlin:

```
requireActivity().findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tab_layout)?.getTabAt(destinationTabNumber)?.select()
```

using `?.` instead of `!!` to avoid asserting.