# Switch ActionBar Tabs from within Fragment, Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am trying to switch between tabs (ActionBarActivity) from within a fragment that is attached to one of the tabs.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315280/how-to-switch-tabs-programatically-in-android-from-fragment) solution:

```
TabHost host = (TabHost) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
host.setCurrentTab(2);
```

but the app crashes when executed, with a NullPointerException at the second line. If I try and get any information about `host`, it all comes back null.

I don't have much Android experience, and so am unsure how to properly get a reference to the parent activity that holds the fragment.

**EDIT**

I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but I've moved the default `SectionsPagerAdapter` to a class of its own.

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity().getTabHost().setCurrentTab(2)
```

Comment: Tried that. It says `cannot resolve method 'getTabHost'`