# Android: Tabs doesn't change

Tags: java, android, tabs

I'have a problem.
Actually i made a TabActivity with 2 Tabs, when i start it i can change the tab and go to the second one, but when i'm in the second one i can't get back to the first one.

How can that be possible?

---

Here's my code:

XML:

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="70dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nome e Cognome"
                android:textColor="@color/cWhite" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/eNome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Nome Cognome"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Categoria segnalazione"
                android:textColor="@color/cWhite" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/eCategoria"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                tools:ignore="TextFields" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="E-mail"
                android:textColor="@color/cWhite" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/eMail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Telefono"
                android:textColor="@color/cWhite" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/eTel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="70dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="ScrollViewSize" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Nome Azienda"
                    android:textColor="@color/cWhite" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/eAzienda"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Nome e Cognome rappresentante"
                    android:textColor="@color/cWhite" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/eRappresentante"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="E-mail Azienda"
                    android:textColor="@color/cWhite" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/eMailAzienda"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Telefono"
                    android:textColor="@color/cWhite" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/eTelAzienda"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="number" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Richiesta"
                    android:textColor="@color/cWhite" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/eRichiesta"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.23"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:maxLines="3" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bInvia"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons_back"
                    android:text="Invia"
                    android:textColor="@color/cWhite" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Java:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.lead_comp);

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();

    TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec1.setIndicator("Indietro");

    TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
    spec2.setIndicator("Avanti");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);

    tabHost.addTab(spec1);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and this post helped me: [how to change tab of a tabactivity from an activity started by the tabactivity ? or change current tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5460651/738262)

Hope this is along the lines of what you are trying to accomplish.

Also, another suggestion would be to use FragmentActivity. I use this anytime I'm working with tabs. Pretty easy to get a firm grasp on it. There are plenty of examples out there.

Hope one of these helps!

Comment: The link for "Scrollable Tabs" is dead. Please update